# Htto 404 Error :Resource Not Found - STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am new to Java Spring MVC.
I created a sample project but i seem to get the Resource NOt found error

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.shr.myapp" />
```

package com.shr.myapp.Controllers.TrampsController.java

```
package com.shr.myapp.Controllers;

import java.util.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TrampsController {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrampsController.class);

 private static List<String> tramps ;

  public TrampsController() {
      tramps= new ArrayList<String>();
      populate(tramps);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/tramps", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String list(Model model) {
    logger.info("Listing Walks");
    model.addAttribute("tramps",tramps);
    return "tramps/list";
  }

private void populate(List<String> tramps) {
    tramps.add("Lake Waikaremoana Great Walk");     
    tramps.add("Kepler Track");
    tramps.add("Milford Track");
    tramps.add("Routeburn Track");
    tramps.add("Rakiura Track");
  }
}
```

WEB-INF/views/tramps/list.jsp;

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/tramps.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>Listing Tramps</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Tramps of New Zealand</h1>


<table class="normal-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="tramp" items="${tramps}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${tramp}"/></td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am not understanding how should i resolve this.Please help me

Comment: please add URL you are using

Comment: Please add the web.xml too

Comment: @Lilith2k3 hi i also provided the web.xml file.please have a look

Comment: @BoboZohdy http://localhost:8080/myapp/WEB-INF/views/tramps/list.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Based on URL you are sharing, you are using wrong URL you have to use

```
localhost:8080/myapp/tramps
```

not

```
localhost:8080/myapp/WEB-INF/views/tramps/list.jsp
```

to invoke controller method, if you are new in spring mvc please check my [YT channel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7350712B99EFC5DD)

Comment: in case his app responds to localhost:8080 ;)

Comment: @Bobo Zohdy How do i set this url?

Comment: you are using @RequestMapping(value = "/tramps", method = RequestMethod.GET) this is mapping "/tramps" to this controller method if you are new in spring MVc check my YT channel here http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7350712B99EFC5DD

Answer (score 0):

I am not for sure this is the root cause of your problem, but your code has at least two errors.

You need to specify "beans" prefix to the bean entry in your servlet-context.xml.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

tramp variable in your list.jsp does not have "key" and "value" property since its type is String.

```
<c:forEach var="tramp" items="${tramps}">
    <tr>
        <td>${tramp}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks for mentioning the mistakes.but i m still getting the same error.is it dat i m making some mistake while re-running the project.i go to list.jsp page->right click ->run as ->run on server.
this is wat i do.